# Child theme functions.php

Tags: functions, child-theme

I'm not sure how to implement a change in my child theme's functions.php.  In the woothemes documentation it says that "The functions.php in your child theme should be empty and not include anything from the parent themes functions.php."

I need to use this function to not display a product category, but I'm not sure how to do this in my child theme.  Perhaps someone can refer me to instructions?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;
if ( ! is_admin() ) {

$q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => array( 'hands-on' ), // Don't display products in the knives category on the shop page
'operator' => 'NOT IN'
)));
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, as it stands, it makes it hard to read and debug

Answer (score 1):

You should put your code in your child theme's `functions.php` file.

I believe that [the documentation you reference](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203105897-How-to-setup-and-use-a-child-theme#pluggable-functions) is referring to the fresh state of the `functions.php` file and the fact that you don't need to copy a parent theme's functions into a child theme to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So do I remove it from the parent to avoid it being overwritten?

Comment: Did you find it in the parent theme's `functions.php` file?

Comment: I did not have a child theme originally, so I added it to the main theme.  Bad practice!

Comment: Yup. Get it out of there. If you put it in both, you'll get an error.